# ngCordova filetransfer not getting path for picture from camera

Tags: ionic-framework, ngcordova

I have a mobile app that I've created where I want users to be able to take a picture and save it to a server.

I've followed the tutorials, but for some reason the file transfer is not working.

Here is my code:

```
$cordovaCamera.getPicture(options).then(function( imageData ) {

                // self.imgURI = "data:image/jpeg;base64," + imageData;

                var server = API_ENDPOINT + '/fileuploads'
                var filePath = "data:image/jpeg; base64," + imageData;

                document.addEventListener('deviceready', function() {

                    $cordovaFileTransfer.upload(server, filePath)
                        .then(function(result) {
                            // Success!
                        }, function(err) {
                            // Error
                        }, function(progress) {
                            // constant progress updates
                        });

                }, false);


            }
```

The Cordova plugin for the camera works great, just an issue with saving the file.

Answer (score 0):

If you are specifically looking to get File Url of the image returned from the Camera plugin, following should be the options for the camera plugin:

```
var options = {
  destinationType: Camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI,
  sourceType: Camera.PictureSourceType.CAMERA,
};
```

[image: check for more http://ngcordova.com/docs/plugins/camera/]

If you are facing any other specific issue, please mention.

Hope this helps.